# Virtual Studio 2008 - ASP.NET - jQuery 1.7.1 VSDoc - JavaScript Intellisense?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, vsdoc

Does anyone have the location to download jQuery 1.7.1 VSDoc?

And also what to do to make it work?  I current have the following and I am a getting massive error in the VSDoc when doing `Ctr-Shift-J` to update Intellisense:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.js"></script>
<% If (False) Then%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.vsdoc.js"></script>
<%  End If%>
```

I have both the Service Pack 1 and the Patch update to make VSDoc work in VS 2008.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like the latest version of jQuery VSDoc is **1.7** not 1.7.1. Version 1.7 can be downloaded from here: http://appendto.com/community/jquery-vsdoc

Comment: Acutally you can access the 1.7.1 version at:  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js

Answer (score 2):

The vs doc is 1.7., but there's no big changes from 1.7. to 1.7.1.

First, rename the 1.7. vsdoc to `jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js`

Second, add the vsdoc file in jquery library folder.

Third, add a line in the javascript file or script section, like: `/// <reference path="/javascript/library/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />`